# Update tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm new to mysql and i've made the following specifications for 3 tables in order to create a simple database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS representative;
CREATE TABLE representative(
    id_representative VARCHAR(15),
    name VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_representative)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS congress;
CREATE TABLE congress(
    id_congress INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_congress)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS representative_congress;
CREATE TABLE representative_congress(
    id_ai INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_representative VARCHAR(15),
    id_congress INT,
    party VARCHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_ai),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_congress) REFERENCES congress(id_congress) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_representative) REFERENCES representative(id_representative) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The information in both the representative and congress tables won't change once inserted (i wouldn't have two equal id_representative for two different representatives, or two equal id_congress for two different congresses). But the representative_congress table is used for the cases in which, in the same congress (time span of 2 years), a given representative would change parties (or even more fields that could be added to the table in the future), so i would have the same id_representative linked to different parties, or even more fields, for the same congress.

With that in mind, i have 2 questions:

- Do i need to add any constraints to the tables's specifications or the insertion queries? Keep in mind that the information will be added to the tables once, being altered only if the tables/database is dropped.
- Is there a way to, with just one INSERT query, insert the
  information that belong to two different tables at once, like a cascade command of some sort? For example, the id_representative, that belongs to both representative and representative_congress tables.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints are good, the primary keys for representative and congress tables ensure the integrity of that information, and the foreign keys in representative_congress prevent to have a wrong relation, the only consideration there is that can't insert into representative_congress before to insert the id's in the previous tables.

The way to insert data in two (or more) tables with only 1 insert statement is with a trigger, but you need to define a default insert or a logic for the insertions, for example

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT
    ON representative FOR EACH ROW
    insert into representative_congress (id_representative, id_congress, party)
    values (NEW.id_representative, 1, '01')
```